# Behaviour of H2 tag next to a floated element

Tags: html, css

I've got some strange behaviour with the following:
**Html**

```
<article class="feature">
  <div class="feature-media">
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="Article Feature media">
  </div>
  <h2>Secondary Title</h2>
  <p>lorum</p>
</article
```

**Css**

```
.feature h2:before {
  content: ""  
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: #df6c4f;
}

.left-main .feature {
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.left-main .feature-media {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Nothing complicated but the H2 tag takes the width of the article and ignores the div to the left. This means that my :before element is hidden behind the image. I've floated all the H2 and the pseudo element which didn't change anything.

Thanks

IMage:
[screenshot http://stage.whenthemusicstops.com/screen.png](http://stage.whenthemusicstops.com/screen.png)

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/HKQj7/ would you mind providing an image of how you'd like it to look like?

Comment: Hi @estrar thanks for your help, I've added an image. As you can see my H2 is expanding and ignoring the div to the left?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `display: block` rule from your `h2` element? I think that might be what's biting you. Keep in mind that floated items live "above" the page, so block level items (like your `h2`) will extend beneath them.

Comment: Like so http://jsfiddle.net/HKQj7/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mtMDn/1/) and it seems to work alright (tested in Chrome).

The only thing I noticed is that you are missing a semicolon after content: "" and I had to remove the .left-main prefix.

```
.feature h2:before {
    content:"";
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background-color: #df6c4f;
}
.feature {
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.feature-media {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```